# Proof of $(\forall x. \varepsilon(x)) \Rightarrow \bot $ in $\lambda\pi $ calculus $\equiv$

Tags: proof-theory, lambda-calculus, type-theory

What is the right representation of the proof of
$(\forall x. \varepsilon(x)) \Rightarrow \bot $ in simple type theory as a term of $\lambda\pi $ calculus $\equiv$?

Note on notation:

The epsilon takes a propositional content and returns a proposition in the simply typed lambda calculus. The lambda pi calculus modulo is just the usual dependently typed lambda calculus that serves as the metalanguage of LF but with a set of reduction rules

Comment: Can you give more details on the notation?

Comment: The epsilon takes a propositional content and returns a proposition in the simply typed lambda calculus. The lambda pi calculus modulo is just the usual dependently typed lambda calculus that serves as the metalanguage of LF but with a set of reduction rules as explained in: http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-878/paper2.pdf.